# Como pasar una variable con ajax a otro archivo php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Buenas tengo un inconveniente con mi codigo, quiero enviarle un dato atraves de un ajax, que me permita hacer una consulta según lo que traiga esta variable, el problema esta en que no me quiere reconocer al momento de hacer el $_POST dicha variable, en ella almaceno el codigo de una Facultad y quiero que según la facultad seleccionada me cargue los datos, si alguien me puede hacer el favor de ayudar seria de mucha ayuda, gracias

Aqui va el codigo de mi select

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="selectFacultad" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Facultad:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><select name="codigoFacultad" id="selectFacultad" class="form-control"  >
                                        <option>Seleccione</option>
                                    </select></div>
                             <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-search" id="buscar" onclick="Cargar()"></button>
                        </div>
```

Ahora siguen los escript en donde tengo la funcion cargar()

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Cargar(){
         var codigoFacultad = $('#selectFacultad').val();
        alert(codigoFacultad);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "llenarPrograma.php",
            data: codigoFacultad,
            success: function(data){
                 $('#contenido').load('llenarPrograma.php');
            }
        });

        }
</script>
```

Acontinuacion el otro archivo que me debe recibir la variable

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");

ob_start();
 mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");

$cod_facultad = $_POST['codigoFacultad']; //Esta es la variable que no me quiere recibir me sale indice indefinido

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT id_programa,nombre_programa,duracion_semestral,horario,metodologia FROM programa WHERE id_facultad= '".$cod_facultad."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0)
{
   echo "<table class='table table-bordered nowrap'> 
            <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th> 
                    <th>Duración semestral</th>
                    <th>Horario</th> 
                    <th>Metodologia</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> "; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id_programa']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['nombre_programa']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['duracion_semestral']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['horario']."</td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['metodologia']."</td>"; 
                echo "</tr>"; 


} 
  "</table>";  
} else { 
echo " <p>Aún no hay registros en la base de datos</p>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola, antes de realizar la llamada ajax prueba mostrar el valor. Algo como `console.log(codigoFacultad);` o `alert(codigoFacultad);` para asegurarnos de que realmente le estas enviando un valor.

Comment: Si claro allí puedes ver que mando un alert() y si me esta tomando el valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionadoo
Aqui les dejo la solución por si se les llega a presentar esta misma dificultad, creanme que sufri mucho hasta que me toco analizarlo detalladamente y utilizar diferentes formas para llegar a su solucion.

Aqui va el codigo del select

```
<div class="form-group" >
                            <label for="selectFacultad" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Facultad:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><select name="selectFacultad" id="selectFacultad" class="form-control"  >
                                        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                    </select></div>
                             <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-search" type="submit" id="buscar" onclick="Cargar();"></button>
                        </div>
```

Tanto el nombre del select como el id deben llamarse igual solo para no generar confusiones, asi mismo va el script de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
        function Cargar(){
            var url="llenarPrograma.php";
            var selectFacultad= document.getElementById("selectFacultad").value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:url,
                data:{selectFacultad:selectFacultad},
                success: function(datos){
                    $('#contenido').html(datos);
                }
            });
        }
     </script>
```

Y por ultimo el archivo llenarPrograma.php

```
<?php
 include_once('conexion.php');

$codigo=$_POST["selectFacultad"];

$resultado=$conexion->query("SELECT id_programa,nombre_programa,duracion_semestral,horario,metodologia FROM programa WHERE id_facultad='$codigo'");

$total=$resultado->num_rows;

if($total>0){
$tabla="<table class='table table-bordered table-success nowrap'>";
$tabla.="<tr><td>Codigo</td><td>Nombre</td><td>Duración</td><td>Horario</td><td>Metodologia</td></tr>";
while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $tabla.="<tr>" ;
    $tabla.="<td>".$row['id_programa']."</td>";
    $tabla.="<td>".$row['nombre_programa']."</td>";
    $tabla.="<td>".$row['duracion_semestral']."</td>";
    $tabla.="<td>".$row['horario']."</td>";
    $tabla.="<td>".$row['metodologia']."</td>";
    $tabla.="</tr>" ;
}
    $tabla.="</table>" ;
    echo $tabla;
}
else{
     echo "<p>Aún no hay registros en la base de datos</p>";
}
?>
```

Espero y le sirva todo, gracias a las personas que me respondieron fue de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas el ajax en el "data" solo se envía el valor de la variable `codigoFacultad`, no se manda una llave "`codigoFacultad`" que en php tratas de acceder `$_POST['codigoFacultad']`

intenta colocando lo siguiente en el data: `{"codigoFacultad" :codigoFacultad }`

Comment: Amigo Cristian Vargas Flores, nada probe eso y no me sirvio, no se que sera

Answer (score 0):

Espero este código te ayude:

a tu variable codigoFacultad modificala por lo siguiente:

```
var codigoFacultad = { 
   "codigoFacultad":$('#selectFacultad').val();
};
```

estarás enviando el nombre que identifica la variable(la que el POST reconoce) y el valor de esa variable.

Comment: Fracisco Castle ya lo habia probado y nada aun no me funciona, me sale cuando lo llamo en el $_POST['codigoFacultad'] como indice indefinido, que no esta declarado

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar a donde vas a enviar el post

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Cargar(){
         var codigoFacultad = $('#selectFacultad').val();
        alert(codigoFacultad);

        /*Le indicas el nombre del del post*/
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('codigoFacultad', codigoFacultad);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "llenarPrograma.php",
            /*Envias los datos*/
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data){
                 $('#contenido').load('llenarPrograma.php');
            }
        });

        }
</script>
```

En php lo recibes así.

```
$cod_facultad = $_POST['codigoFacultad'];
```

Y en tu codigo HTML te falta el value en los option del select, tendrian que estar asi.

```
<select name="codigoFacultad" id="selectFacultad" class="form-control"  >
   <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
   <option value="1">Facultad 1</option>
   <option value="2">Facultad 2</option>
</select>
```

Te recomiendo que a tu select el nombre y el id sea el mismo, ya que puede llegar a producir confusión. Y también tu sentencia SQL es muy susceptible a sql injection te recomiendo que revises como pasar por parámetros o PDO.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero aun no me funciona me sigue saliendo indice indefinido, sinceramente no se como hacerlo ya, e intentado de todas las formas y nada aún

Comment: agrega esto en ajax debajo de dateType,   "cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false," me falto agregarlo a la respuesta.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, no entiendo el porque, me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: bueno verifica en el alert que si te este regresando el valor del select y cambia esta parte en el "success $('#contenido').load('llenarPrograma.php');" por esta "$('#contenido').html(data);"

Comment: Le añadi lo ultimo que me mandaste, verifique si me tomaba el codigo y si lo esta tomando la variable, pero lo de "$('#contenido').htmlt(data); me muestra es simplemente : "data". al momento de realizarlo